# SwiftUI: Button Style doesn't work when menu is presented after tapping on a button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my app, I wish to add a functionality where when a button is tapped, menu should be presented with a list of items.

All this is working fine except the text/foreground color of the button happens to be same as the background color of the view on which button is placed. In my sample code below it happens to be white color. When menu is presented, looks like iOS fades or reduces opacity of button's background and foreground and because of this the text on the button is not visible.

I wish have the button text visible in some color and hence I added button style, but it doesn't work when menu is presented. It works on regular button taps, but not with menu. How to change the button foreground/background when menu is presented? I am using iOS 16+.

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSignInOptionsView = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Menu {
                Button {} label: {
                    Text("Menu 1")
                }
                Button {} label: {
                    Text("Menu 2")
                }
                Button {} label: {
                    Text("Menu 3")
                }
            } label: {
                Button { showSignInOptionsView.toggle() } label: {
                    Text("Sign In").frame(maxWidth: .infinity).contentShape(Rectangle())
                }
                .buttonStyle(SignInButtonStyle())
            }

// Note: button style works on this since it's regular button. Uncomment to test.
//            Button { showSignInOptionsView.toggle() } label: {
//                Text("Sign In - Regular Button").frame(maxWidth: .infinity).contentShape(Rectangle())
//            }
//            .buttonStyle(SignInButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}

private struct SignInButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
        .font(.body.bold())
        .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? .black : .white)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50.0, height: 30.0)
        .padding(10.0)
        .background(configuration.isPressed ? .gray : .blue)
        .cornerRadius(10.0)
    }
}
```

***Screenshots:*** I wish to have button text clearly visible in the right screenshot i.e. when menu is open.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Note, according to the docs [Menu label](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/init(content:label:)) and [Menu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu), the label part of the `Menu` should be a `Label`, not a `Button`

Comment: Label conforms to a View and you can have any view elements in place of Label. I had been through certain examples before I used Button as a label. Anyways, they way I fixed it is by replacing button with regular Text element and created MenuStyle instead of button style. Will add my solution for future reference for others.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it. It's not quite what I wanted, but still better results than using Button as a label. I replaced button style with menu style and removed the button element.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSignInOptionsView = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Menu {
                Button {} label: {
                    Text("Menu 1")
                }
                Button {} label: {
                    Text("Menu 2")
                }
                Button {} label: {
                    Text("Menu 3")
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Sign In").frame(maxWidth: .infinity).contentShape(Rectangle())
            }
            .menuStyle(SignInMenuStyle())
        }
    }
}

private struct SignInMenuStyle: MenuStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Menu(configuration)
            .font(.body.bold())
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50.0, height: 30.0)
            .padding(10.0)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
    }
}
```